# Android OS 2.2 Permissions: I have absolutely no idea why this simple piece of code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, time, permissions, operating-system

I'm just playing around with some code. I create an Activity and simply do something like this:

```
long lo = currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(lo);

lo *= 3;
System.out.println(lo);

SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(lo);
System.out.println( currentTimeMillis() );
```

Yes, in my AndroidManifest.xml, I've added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"></uses-permission>
```

Nothing changes. The SystemClock is never reset...it just keeps on ticking.
The error that I'm getting just says that the permission "SET_TIME" was not granted to the program. Protection level 3.

The permissions are there...and in the API for 2.2 it says that this feature is supported now. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

If android.content.Intent; comes into play, please explain. I don't really understand what the idea behind intents!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does logcat indicate anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a SET_TIME_ZONE permission but there's no SET_TIME permission. Applications cannot programmatically change the system clock.

**Update**

SET_TIME is available since 2.2, but can only be granted to the system process or apps signed with the system signature.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_TIME, it's available since API 8. What's the deal?

Comment: Indeed it is in the 2.2 docs, I just realized I was checking the 2.0 source code instead of 2.2. Sorry about the confusion.

I checked the 2.2 source code and the SET_TIME permission can only be granted to applications signed with the system signature. This mean you cannot use this permission.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Is the protection level for a given permission documented anywhere or is it required to look at AndroidManifest.xml in the source?

Comment: Is it possible to write a user level application with the system signature??

If not then I'm kind of annoyed as to why the Android developers would release this :(

Comment: No you cannot use the system signature. Unless you can get it from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

using AlarmManager with SET_TIME permission to set system time seems to work :)

Comment: On which API-Level have you tested this? I Always get an Exception saying: "java.lang.SecurityException: setTime: Neither user 10041 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME." I set the permission: "android.permission.SET_TIME" in my Manifest. Can anybody confirm that?

Comment: @Hemeroc Same here. Tested on API level 8. Looks like the application must be signed with system certificate.

Answer (score -3):

insetad of System.out.println() use Log.v() or similar.

I think I found your error, please try it out: Remove 
   `</uses-permission>`
 on both lines, that should work

Comment: Log.*() is better, but System.out.println() works. <uses-permission></uses-permission> is the same as <uses-permission/>. The latter is just a short version of the former.

Comment: As @Romain said, <tag /> is really a short hand of <tag></tag> which is empty.