# How-to set Android device date/time programmatically

Tags: android, adb, galaxy

**BACKGROUND**

I am working on a project using the Wi-fi only version of the Samsung Galaxy tab (7"). On some of the devices we are seeing the date/time on the device getting reset (don't know why) to some date in the past (like 1/1/2000).

**QUESTION(S)**

How can I programmatically reset the device date/time? I'd prefer to use some adb shell command if possible (my shell scripting is rusty). If there is no shell command that can accomplish this, is there a way to accomplish this by writing and installing an app (seems like a security violation)?

Answer (score 31):

You can use the next command:

> adb shell date -s YYYYMMDD.HHmmss

example:

> adb shell date -s 20120423.130000

sets the date to `Mon Apr 23 13:00:00 CEST 2012` (my phone is on CEST time zone)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to get the time from a windows machine and set it as android time ?

Comment: Sorry, not a Windows user

Comment: hi its nice,there any method to exicute this command on my application apk using java code

Comment: @harsha.kuruwita you could [run a shell command within an app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882248/running-shell-commands-though-java-code-on-android) but need a rooted device

Comment: @harsha.kuruwita this post explains [how to change the system time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584772/is-possible-to-set-system-datetime-from-my-android-app)

Comment: This was the only one that worked out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2):

I made this `perl` script to handle this problem:

**`clock.pl`**

```
use Time::localtime;
$_=localtime;
system'adb','shell','date -s',sprintf("%04d%02d%02d.%02d%02d%02d",$_->year+1900,$_->mon+1,$_->mday,$_->hour,$_->min,$_->sec)
```

Call it using `cmd` (*windows*) or `terminal` (*mac*):

```
perl < clock.pl
```

The android clock will be instantly updated with your machine time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shell's 'date' command.  With an argument of unix epoch time (i.e. seconds since 1/1/70) it sets the device's clock, e.g. 'adb shell date  1318349236'.

You can get the current timestamp in seconds with 'adb shell date +%s'.  If you have busybox, the date command is more capable, and you can get your arbitrary desired date in seconds with 'busybox date +%s -d "2010-01-01 12:34:56"'

Comment: When I try  
    adb shell date 1319124916  
  
I get this  
    time 1319124916 -> 1319124916.0  
    settimeofday failed Bad file number

Comment: On Linux I use: adb shell date -s \`date "+%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"\`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following commands to correctly format date and time in windows and the set system time on android

```
set datetimef=%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%date:~-4%.%time:~6,2%
adb shell date -d %datetimef%
```

This does set the unix system time of Android but does not change the hardware clock. The time displayed by android gui is also not influenced this way.

I guess hwclock command should be used to update the hardware clock, but this does not execute due to permission errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change Date based on Your system date

**Change Date same as system**

```
adb shell date -s `date +%G%m%d.%H%M%S`
```

**Change Date to tomorrow:**

```
adb shell date -s `date --date='1 day' +%G%m%d.%H%M%S`
```

**Change Date to Tomorrow 12 AM**

```
adb shell date -s `date --date='1 day' +%G%m%d.000000`
```

**Change Date to Yesterday**

```
 adb shell date -s `date --date='1 day ago' +%G%m%d.%H%M%S`
```

**Change Date to week ago**

```
adb shell date -s `date --date='1 week ago' +%G%m%d.%H%M%S`
```