# Set Android's date/time programmatically

Tags: java, android, system-clock

I need set the date/time from Android programmatically, but I'm not having success!
I have these three sources above:

Source code 1

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
alarm.setTime(1330082817000);
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
```

Exception:

```
Service fatal error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.tdta.service/br.com.tdta.service.Service}: java.lang.SecurityException: setTime: Neither user 10038 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME.  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.tdta.service/br.com.tdta.service.Service}: java.lang.SecurityException: setTime: Neither user 10038 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME.  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)  
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)  
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)  
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)  
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: setTime: Neither user 10038 nor current process has android.permission.SET_TIME.  
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)  
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)  
    at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.setTime(IAlarmManager.java:237)  
    at android.app.AlarmManager.setTime(AlarmManager.java:289)  
    at br.com.tdta.service.Service.onCreate(Service.java:32)  
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)  
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)  
... 11 more
```

====

Source code 2

```
boolean itsWork = SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(1330082817000);  
System.out.println(itsWork);
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
```

**itsWork** value:

```
false
```

====

Source code 3

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd.hhmmss");
String data = format.format(new Date(1330082817000));
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date -s " + data);
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will only work on a rooted phone. And a followup here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584772/is-possible-to-set-system-datetime-from-my-android-app

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752130/1833118) works for me on a rooted phone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The user application does not have permission to change the device time. Please read the answer by cashbash in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android) for the alternate option.

Copying here for quick reference:

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/hVrk_mldPnA), user apps cannot set the time, regardless of the permissions we give it. Instead, the best approach is to make the user set the time manually. We will use:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to link them directly to the time setting (which would save them one more click). By making use of `ellapsedRealtime`, we can ensure that the user sets the time correctly.

Comment: thanks! I solved using this: `startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));`

Comment: Late update, but maybe you should check instead the anser by me in the referenced question thread. It's not a big deal as long as you can get the SET_TIME permission.

Comment: How to get android os time and date that did set in android setting? Does Date() return those?