# Is there a way to change to a specified date?

Tags: android, date

I want to know if is there a way to change to a specified date, launch an intent of an app and seconds later, turn the automatic date programmatically.

- Change System Date
- Launch an intent
- Turn back the automatic date of the carrier

Thanks, Could It be possible?

Comment: what you want to say please clear

Comment: I want to make an app with this purpose:

1. Change the system date.
2. Launch an Intent.
3. Restore the automatic date of the Settings.

I don't know how to do the steps 1 and 3.

Comment: step 1 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584772/is-possible-to-set-system-datetime-from-my-android-app

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to get the time from the Network Provider. You may use this code. There are plenty of other solutions that you will find, if you Google it.

```
 LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
long networkTS = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but what about step 1? Change the system date. Could It be possible?

Comment: I think this post has an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android

Comment: It's not possible :S at least on not rooted phones :S

Comment: Yes, you're right Victor, only a System user can change system time, you need the SET_TIME permission and that permission is granted by system only to applications that are in the Android system image.

Comment: If I use a library like RootTools, Could I  make this possible?

Comment: I am afraid this will not help you.  
roottools will work only for the Rooted Android devices. This library is design to help user to use root operations easily.

Comment: Yes, I have assumed that only work on rooted phones. Then for rooted phones I can get it?

Comment: Victor, may I know the situation where you need to change the Date Time, so we can find a better solution?