# Can I programmatically change time on device?

Tags: android

How to adjust device time from my application? Especially with tablets, as tablets do not sync time as phones do.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? I'd uninstall any app which messed with the time on my device.

Comment: I assume it's Java you're working with; if that's the case your answer has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454315/how-do-you-format-date-and-time-in-android).

Comment: @MisterSquonk This is not market app that you choose. This is corporate app and unfortunately tablets do not sync time as phones do. We seeing all kinds of issues. Ther is always someone with time 1:30 minutes off..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Try

```
 AlarmManager a = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        a.setTime(millis);
```

Don't forget permission `SET_TIME` in your manifest.

Comment: Seems like it is not available to "general" public. Have you tried it yourself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918624/android-os-2-2-permissions-i-have-absolutely-no-idea-why-this-simple-piece-of-c

Comment: What do you mean by "binding admin to device" ?

Comment: Nevermind it. I just got misinterpreted http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html  I thought DPM can change the time as well.