# How to test Alarm Manager which set for a INTERVAL_DAY

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I written a small application which invokes a service using AlarmManager with interval of the day. To test this app, i am using emulator 5.1 . When i set manually date and time(for current date or future date time) the AlarmManager invokes service for that day. When i am trying to change the date for checking whether it will work for other day by changing date then its not invoking service.

Here is my code.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);
        calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE,20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,10);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);


        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

BackgroundService is service which popup with a Toast .

I have 2 issues.

1. How can test AlarmManager , which we set with Interval of a day?
2. The Alarm Manager is not exactly invoking at the second. For example , i set the alarm at 13:20:10 but its coming at 13:20:some Random second

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. RTC (Real Time Clock) is the clock that you can adjust, so you could possibly just change the current time programatically for a test case. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18104950/4191629)
2. You're using a `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating` method, which doesn't guarantee an exact time of alarm delivery. For more precise timings, use `alarmManager.setRepeating`, however keep in mind that it's not really recommended, as most use cases do not require exact timings and it will cause higher battery usage. See [inexactRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and [repeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: but if i am using setRepeating then how can i make an alarm everyday at particular time only once

Comment: By using the setReapting, although i changed date to next day irrespective of date and time its executing      recursively.alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000*60,pendingIntent);                                           used adb shell to change date to next day. i actually set the time to 13:20. But when i set the date and time to next day 13:15 still the alarm is executing.