# Is it possible to change the time with an android application?

Tags: android, wifi, mobile-devices

I have a device with android that connects to wi-fi with a certificate. The certificate has a specific validity time. If the battery is removed or completely discharged, the time is reset. This results in the inability to connect to wi-fi and download the correct time. For security reasons, the settings are locked in the device and I would like to create an application that will set the time to a fixed time in the code. Then the phone will connect to the network and download the correct one. Do you have any other suggestions on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you need a root device, plus the "SET_TIME" permission.
that's a system permission so you can't do that in a Play Store app.

Then you can use the AlarmManager to set the time you want.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2021, 11, 19, 11, 46, 00);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

EDIT: [How to set time to device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939572/how-to-set-time-to-device-programmatically/18104950)

Geobits's answers this better than me in a really similar way.